# Hibernate doesn't create tables automatically

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have Maven project with Hibernate/Spring/MySQL. I have basic entity and I want Hibernate to create tables automatically, but Hibernate doesn't create any tables. No exceptions are thrown too, so I have no idea what is wrong here.

application.properties:

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/task
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 12345678
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=3600000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

User.java:

```
package com.example.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "telegramId")
    private Integer telegramId;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
            )
    private List<Message> msg = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In User.java I also use lombok. Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: try to add `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` to your properties

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you tried doing some unit testing? Create a Repository to insert / extract data from the DB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was that Application.java was in package `com.example.BotApp.`, now it's in `com.example.`. I don't know, but somehow it helped.

Comment: That means that your entity class was not being picked up by spring boot annotations scanning (which by default scans current package and it's subpackages). It is explained on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html . If your main class has it's own package like `com.example.boot`, you will need to add the `scanBasePackages`, like so: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example" })` in order to scan everything in other packages

Comment: the same occurred to me...when I created the packages as a child of Application.java package, then everything worked

Answer (score 5):

you are missing this property in your properties file

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto="update"

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is automatically validates and exports DDL to schema when the sessionFactory is created.

By default, It is not doing any creation or modification automatically on db. If user sets  values to **update or create or validate or create-drop** then it is doing DDL  schema changes automatically according to given value.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `spring-data` (which I hope you are), remove the `@Table` annotation, Spring will automatically create a table with the name *user* just from the `@Entity`. The minimum config that should go inside your `application.propertes` is this:

```
# Hibernate
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# Mysql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://yourdburl:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true // creates a schema if doesn't exist
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345678
```

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` will update your DB table (if necessary) every time your app connects to it. It should also create it if there is none.
Other values are
`create` and `create-drop` which are pretty much self-explanatory

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. Following may be one of the reason.

In my case:

Earlier,
configuration class was inside **com.abc.school** package and
my entity class was inside **com.abc.entity** package.

So , package name for entity class was not correct.
It should be **com.abc.school.entity**

Answer (score 0):

Put property **spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true** above the **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto = update** to resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have the same package as the package of your main application then you have to add @EntityScan("package where to find the entitys").

**Edit:**  Normal Spring Boot package scan doesnt recognize outside of the application base package where entities are therefore you can use @EntityScan which allows to scan independently from @ComponentScan to scan for JPA entities. Heres the javadoc for @EntityScan https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

test changing the name of the table, this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

in my case, I believe that, because I was using hibernate 5, hibernate 5 should solve some format problems for the columns table automatically, some tables were not created, but others were.
I DIFF the files to analyze the differences...and the problem was...
I was using a property and that impeded the creating of the table...

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(6,6) DEFAULT 0.00")
private Double longitude;
```

I've deleted `columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(6,6) DEFAULT 0.00"`, and the tables were created normally.